# on_guild_channel_update is ignored in newest update

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

In newest update, I have a problem with event: on_guild_channel_update.
I mean, in 1.6.0 it was worked, but in 1.7.0 now have a problem

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = get_prefix, intents = intents)

@client.event
async def on_guild_role_update(before, after):
    global check_ranga
    #e = discord.Embed(color = client.get_user(id_arnoldzika).color, timestamp = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc))
    async for author in before.guild.audit_logs(limit = 1, oldest_first = False, action = discord.AuditLogAction.role_update):
        member = '{0.user.id}'.format(author)
        user = await client.fetch_user(member)
        print(user)

@client.event
async def on_guild_channel_update(before, after):
    global check_position
    check = 0
    e = discord.Embed(color = client.get_user(id_arnoldzika).color, timestamp = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc))
    async for author in before.guild.audit_logs(limit = 1, oldest_first = False, action = discord.AuditLogAction.channel_update):
        print('{0.before} {0.after.type}'.format(author))
        member = '{0.user.id}'.format(author)
        user = await client.fetch_user(member)
```

When trigger channel update, I don't get anything, but when trigger role update, correctly print user.
What is the problem with this?

Comment: It works for me, try printing something, maybe there's something wrong with the code inside of the event

Comment: But it worked on 1.6.0 not in 1.7.0

Comment: I give something before async for... and only this is printed

Comment: This is so very intresting problem, on my laptop this same function working, but on main computer not

Comment: Try to add intents.members = True.

Comment: But I have for all, so it isn't a problem